# not connecting to home wifi

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and everything is great except I can't connect to my home network. I can connect fine to my mobile hotspot but not my home network. I have google wifi router so it could be something to do with that but I don't know. So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me.  I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and was not able to connect to home Wi-Fi.

I then used a network cable to connect via LAN  to the internet, ran Ubuntu software upgrade, installed all the updates and restarted the computer.  This fixed the issue!